Why was ~/.local/share selected as the default directory for $XDG_DATA_HOME?
I'm puzzled about the purpose of ~/.local/share. It holds user-specific data, implying it shouldn't be shared among users. Moreover, one application (app_B) typically shouldn't access or manipulate data belonging to another application (app_A). So, what's the rationale for sharing?
Consider this scenario: I'm developing a blob-database for individual user use. Where would be the appropriate place to store this data? Is ~/.local/share the right fit? But again: what does the share dir share?
